# Android : How to parse the XML Attributes

Tags: android

XMLParser.Java

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import android.util.Log;

public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }   

}
```

Test XML File

```
http://sathishm.com/test.xml
```

XMLActivity.java

```
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://sathishm.com/test.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "row"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "rank";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "metro_area";
    static final String KEY_COST = "durum";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "latitude";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
            map.put(KEY_COST, "Rs." + parser.getValue(e, KEY_COST));
            map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
```

Guys, please look into the XML file. I can able to get the all XML values from the URL, can you please tell me how can i get the XML attributes. Example how can i get the "location" attributes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use some thing like:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
InputStream input = entity.getContent();

andchange your method:

getDomElement(InputStream xmlStream){

Document document = db.parse(xmlStream);
}
```

and in your XMLActivity.java do somthing like

```
static final String URL = "http://sathishm.com/test.xml";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "row"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "rank";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "metro_area";
    static final String KEY_COST = "durum";
    static final String KEY_DESC = "latitude";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
       InputStream stream = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(stream); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            NodeList childList=e.getElementByTagName("your tag");
            Element childElement=(Element)childList.item(0);
            String value;
            Node child = e.getFirstChild();
           if (child instanceof CharacterData) {
       CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) child;
       value=cd.getData();
            }
           // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map.put(KEY_ID,value);


            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

On an Element you found while browing the Document (here a location element) :

```
String latitude = locationElement.getAttribute("latitude");
```

Your parser is not really clear though !